# How to put objects in column in Django templates

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I'm developing an ecommerce project. It's my first time with Django, so be patient.
I have some objects in a list, whith so many fields.
I want to put this object in column in my template.
I tried with the  but in a for loop it doesn't recognize more than one div.
Is there a method to incolumn my object in my template?
Here's my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XmqX.png)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is nothing to do from backend. you need to handle it in frontend.
You can use a table to display the data as shown below

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Codice</th>
        <th>produttore</th>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for l in listprodotti %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{l.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{l.codice_prodotto}}</td>
            <td>{{l.prodottore}}</td>
            ....
        <tr>
        {% ednfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For adding extra styles check bootstrap

If you dont want to display them in a table, you can enclose the for loop in a div and add the below css.

```
<div class="card">
    {% for l in listprodotti %}
     <div>
       ...  
     </div>  
    {% ednfor %}
</div>
```

**#in styles (css) file**

```
.card{
    display: flex;
    gap:15px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: It works! But if i put at least 3 object, it put them in only two columns. One on the left and two on the right, one under the other.

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I charged the screenshot here:  ibb.co/ZLpZsmg This is the way in which the div are created: https://ibb.co/FnD7ns3    Thank you

Comment: @FILIPPOREGGIANI The link you shared is not working

Comment: I tried and it works for me. Anyway i resolve the problem, I used flexbox. In my code i made an error because don’t closing the <i> it broke everything. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write what you're using for the front end, but maybe [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/) would be a good alternative.

Comment: I tried like this, i put the <div container> e the <div row> outside the for loop and the <div column> inside the loop, but it put inside the <div column 1> the <div column 2>